# Trying to plot to scatter plot but getting different plot, it is for forecasting for next year what is the problem behind this result?

Tags: r, data-visualization, scatter-plot, data-analysis

I am trying plot to scatter plot but it is not happening,

I am providing my data image here ->
 [My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1HXH.png)

My data frame name is linear_data,

I am applying this code,

```
 plot(linear_data)
```

And I am getting this plot

[image: Plot of linear data]

What should I do here to plot to scatter plot and I am using this data to do forecasting for another year month wise?

Comment: Post complete code

Comment: please add an actually reproducible sample of your data, use `dput(linear_data)`. If `linear_data` is very big, use `dput(head(linear_data,20))`

Comment: I am guessing that `Month_of_absence` is a variable of type character or factor, not numeric as you assumed, so `plot` assumes it is categorical and you get a boxplot by default. Confirm using `str(linear_data)`.

Comment: Hello, Om Prakash sao, I have written just this line of code.

Comment: Yes, neilfws the variable of Month is a factor, I have converted it into numerical but still not getting proper scatter plot.

Comment: Hie boski, as per your code I got this output: structure(list(Month_of_absence = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9), Absenteeism_time_in_hours = c(4, 
0, 2, 4, 2, 2.66297434341193, 8, 4, 40, 8, 8, 8, 8, 1, 4, 4.57149528415633, 
2, 8, 8, 2)), .Names = c("Month_of_absence", "Absenteeism_time_in_hours"
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @HiMeshNaGar don't forget you need to go factor->character->numeric for that conversion; something like `as.numeric(as.character(linear_data$Month_of_absence))`.

Comment: @neilfws I did it but not getting an appropriate graph yet.

Answer (score 0):

I plotted exactly what your `dput()` showed and got the following graph.

```
> zz=structure(list(Month_of_absence = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9), Absenteeism_time_in_hours = c(4, 0, 2, 4, 2, 2.66297434341193, 8, 4, 40, 8, 8, 8, 8, 1, 4, 4.57149528415633, 2, 8, 8, 2)), .Names = c("Month_of_absence", "Absenteeism_time_in_hours" ), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
> plot(zz)
```

[image: figure]

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No, thank you but I was not looking for this. I found the solution by aggregate the data as per months and then after plotting I got the result.